# How Can I use useTheme() in class components in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, theming

Currently I want to use useTheme() but as its hook that I can not use it in class component. But its my compulsion to use it in class components can any one tell me how can I use?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what library you are using (`useTheme()` is not part of React or React Native) it is hard to answer specific to your use case. Because hooks can only be used in Functional components, you can wrap your class component in one. For example:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <p>Hello!</p>
    }
}

export default function(props) {
    const theme = useTheme()

    return <MyComponent {...props} theme={theme}/>
}
```

Comment: Is it a best practice to wrap components in cases like this?

Comment: I would say it probably depends on the library the OP is using. If the library has some alternative that doesn't use hooks (a provider, or higher-order component, for example) I would probably use that. Given that the question didn't state which library he is using it is hard to say.

This doesn't answer the question if he needs to use a class component for some reason, but I find it best to use functional components as much as possible (easier to read, and less code). Since React 16 came out I haven't ever found myself in a situation where I absolutely HAVE to use a class component.

Answer (score 0):

React Navigation did not state an alternative, but you can wrap your class component in a function component and pass it as a props